# Error reading from 2nd USB camera when setting identical frame size for two cameras

Tags: opencv, height, width, frame, dimension

I am facing a weird situation. I have two USB cameras attached to my laptop (windows 10 Home) via USB-C Hub. The issue I am facing is that python 3.x / OpenCV  don't read from 2nd camera if  I set the frame height and width similar for both cameras. If i change the parameters even slightly, it works. Need help to understand what is going on. The image is attached with the red markings.

If dimensions are (Frame height, width) same then the first camera returns "True" and the second one returns "False" (Marked in debugger window).

Thanks very much.

```
Code # 1 - Doesnt work, both cameras have same height/width params

my_cams1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
my_cams1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
my_cams1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

my_cams2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
my_cams2.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
my_cams2.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)

Code # 2 - It works, 1st camera has difference frame height as compared to other one
my_cams1 = cv2.VideoCapture(1, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
my_cams1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
my_cams1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 450)

my_cams2 = cv2.VideoCapture(2, cv2.CAP_DSHOW)
my_cams2.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_WIDTH, 640)
my_cams2.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 480)
```

[image]

Comment: check `isOpened` *once* after creating each object. cameras are indexed starting from 0, so if you have exactly two cameras, they're 0 and 1.

Comment: Can you try a lower resolution for both cameras (identical) ? If that works I guess it's a bandwidth issue. When you set `my_cams1.set(cv2.CAP_PROP_FRAME_HEIGHT, 450)` I'm pretty sure that value is not available (it's not a supported resolution since 450 is not that common) and the resolution get defaulted to the default value, which maybe is a lower value.. that's a possible reason for that working..

Comment: I started with low resolution and gradually moved  upto 800 * 640. So far no issues and cameras are operating as expected.  Put the cameras on USB 3 and USB 2 ports too, all working well. Not sure what exactly caused the issue.

Comment: Hi Christoph .. my apologies i should have mentioned that the built-in camera on the laptop got index 0, but I am not using it.